# flutter convert two lists to one map

Tags: flutter, dart

what is the best way to convert these two Lists

```
    var list1 =[a, b, c]
    var list2 =[1 ,2, 3]
```

to this Map

```
Map<dynamic,dynamic> Map1 = {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
      "c": 3,
    };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a built-in for that:

```
final theMap = Map.fromIterables(list1, list2);
```

You should really review the protocol of the major core types (List, Map, Set, and so on) on at least a monthly basis.  I still do!

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the keys and add the elements from the second list as value. The two lists should be at least the same length, otherwise you are accessing an index that does not exist.

```
  var list1 =["a", "b", "c"];
  var list2 =[1 ,2, 3];
  var map = {};
  for(int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
    map[list1[i]] = list2[i];
  }
  print(map);
```